# How to change a value of an array which is indexed several times?

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

Let's have A like below :

```
A = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

And now, I have to take all the lines which have a 1 on first column :

```
A[A[:, 0] > 0]
return: array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

And now, I want to modify the first column of the second line ? How can I do it ? Because this is not working :

```
A[A[:, 0] > 0][1, 1] = 1
A
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 3, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

My code is more complicated than this one, and so, the condition have to be done in two times like here : (1) > 0 and (2) [1, 1].

Comment: `A[A[:,0]>0]` is a copy of a portion of `A`, it is not a `view`.  `...[1,1]=1` modifies that new array, not `A`.  You'll have to figure out a way of combining the two levels of indexing if you want to do this assignment.

Comment: Ok it's more clear now. I start to understand why the value it's not changing. I'm going to look at the web if a solution exist ! thank's

Comment: Ok, so I stored the index of all values which were superior to 0 into a vector. Then it was simplier to opperate on the initial array :)